# resizing freebsd partition

Tags: freebsd

I have  Windows, Linux and FreeBSD on my computer. But accidentally i "forgot" to allocate 17 gb of free disk space on the end of the disk(and "bad" Windows is using a little primary restore partition. Thus i have 4 primary partitions now). Can i resize my FreeBSD partition, to capture free space?
There is my disk partitioning.

```
$ gpart show     
    =>       63  488397105  ada0  MBR  (232G)
             63       1985        - free -  (992k)
           2048     716800     1  ntfs  (350M)
         718848  313856000     2  ntfs  (149G)
      314574848       2046        - free -  (1M)
      314576894   83996674     3  ebr  (40G)
      398573568         27        - free -  (13k)
      398573595   52428726     4  freebsd  [active]  (25G)
      451002321   37394847        - free -  (17G) // Free space i wanna allocate

    =>       0  83996674  ada0s3  EBR  (40G)
             0  29997058       1  linux-data  (14G)
      29997058      2028          - free -  (1M)
      29999086  49997844  476176  linux-data  (23G)
      79996930      1980          - free -  (990k)
      79998910   3997764  1269824  linux-swap  (1.9G)

    =>       0  52428726  ada0s4  BSD  (25G)
             0  52428725       1  freebsd-ufs  (25G)
      52428725         1          - free -  (512B)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at gpart's `resize` command. That should enable you to grow the partition. You can then grow the UFS filesystem in the partition with growfs(8).

Do make a backup of your filesystem before trying this!

Comment: Just to add, since FreeBSD 10, you can grow file systems that are mounted/live.  https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disks-growing.html

Comment: @LucasHolt While it is *possible* to do this with a live UFS fs, that does *not* make it a good idea. For the simple reason that such a situation was probably not foreseen when UFS was designed. These days, using ZFS is probably the simplest way to have easily expandable storage on FreeBSD.

Comment: That's what backups are for.  In cloud environments, it's often the most convenient way to manage despite the risk.

Comment: Actually, in FreeBSD resizing a live UFS file system is a safe, fully supported mechanism.  It's not something that works "by accident" - there's the write suspension mechanism designed specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

growfs(8) works well for the UFS case. If you are using ZFS, you will want to `zpool online -e`  the zpool after expanding the partition (slice).